# Change Samba password from Windows client

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, password, samba

I set up a Samba server on Ubuntu 12.04 in a network with five clients running Windows 7. We're not using a domain, just a workgroup. Everything is working fine.

Is there a way users can change their Samba passwords from their Windows clients? Preferably not involving an ssh client but using a web-interface or even a native Windows method.

Edit:

Using Usermin for now. It works but it's a bit overkill, I'm curious if you know any more elegant solutions.

Edit 2:

Contents of /etc/samba/smb.conf global section:

```
[global]
 workgroup = MYWORKGROUP
 server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
 dns proxy = no
 log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
 max log size = 1000
 syslog = 0
 panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

 security = user
 encrypt passwords = true
 passdb backend = tdbsam
 obey pam restrictions = yes
 unix password sync = yes
 passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
 passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
 pam password change = yes
 map to guest = bad user
 guest account = smbguest
 usershare allow guests = yes
```

Comment: Can you add contents of `smb.conf`?

Comment: I could but is that relevant? The question goes just as well for the default Ubuntu 12.04 config, regardless of what I changed.

Comment: Does it have [This](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5778054/) in it?

Comment: It does. I added the global section to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without a domain you can't have a Microsoft Windows client use native windows methods to change passwords on other machines.

However, you could set up a simple web form on the server running samba that they can log in to, for changing their samba password, that just runs [smbpasswd](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbpasswd.8.html).

Comment: Ok, I'm guess then I'm looking for that simple web form you mention. I could write one myself but perhaps someone else has already made one that is safer than how I would do it.